# Event bus route algorithm

Tags: algorithm

i want to create an algorithm for the following problem:

Multiple departures around where i need to pick up a number of people and drive them to a fixed destination. E.g.
Karlsruhe (15)
Stuttgart (30)
Dresden (4)
Munich (20)

And i need to create the "optimal" amount of buses and their routes. A bus has a max amount of capacity (e.g. 50).

The best solution of the above is

- Route 1 - Karlsruhe, Stuttgart
- Route 2 - Dresden, Munich

Additional Infos:

- Everyone goes to the same location
- We can assume that the busses magically appear at the first pickup spot

EDIT

- Optimal should be the sum of the distance travelled by all busses

Currently, i have no good idea on how to start the problem. The calculation could create all permutations of the input routes, check if the people would fit in, and if yes check the overall distance of all created routes of these permutations. But this could be very time-consuming if i do not only have 4 but more destinations.

Do you guys know a good algorithm that could help me there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does everyone want to go to the same location? Do the buses start in a fixed location, or do they just "magically" appear at the first pickup spot? And what is "optimal"? Least time, least buses, or some compromise of the two?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Added the info about this in the question

Comment: "Optimal is the least amount of busses" So distance does not play a roll at all? In this case, this is just the [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), right? Good news: It's very well researched; bad news: still NP-Hard... but there are good approximations.

Comment: Why KS + DM the best solution? SM (50) + KD (19) would also fit into two buses.

Comment: Ok, you are right. The distance is something i need to keep into account

Comment: Not sure if that's optimal (probably not), but have you tried greedy? 1) pick city closest to drop-off point; b) pick city closest to drop-off point _or_ starting point of any bus route with sufficient capacity; iii) repeat until all cities are covered.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and questions. I think I found the right solution for my problem: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp I will try this Google library - this should solve it.